# Is there a way to set up a fallback for the <input> formAction attribute in HTML5?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, modernizr

I have a form that is supposed to dynamically change where it is submitted to. I am doing this by bringing in a submit button using ajax that has the formAction attribute set to where I want the form to submit to (I'm bringing in a number of other things as well that are dependent on the user input, but as far as I can tell have no bearing on this question). Here's an example of my submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Edit" name="save" id="save" formAction="http://example.com" />
```

The URL in formAction is dynamically generated based on user input in the initial form.

Everything is working as I expected in both chrome and firefox, but despite the fact that IE 11 supposedly has support for formAction, it appears to be ignoring it. Regardless, I'd like to have the same functionality work with IE 9, which I know doesn't support formAction, so I'm trying to create a fallback.

I've used Modernizr in the past, but looking at the [documentation](http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-html5) indicates to me that it does not check for the formAction attribute. Is there a way to use the html 5 functionality of formAction while having a fallback option? I like to try to code to html 5 standards whenever possible.

Comment: This site is reporting that IE9 accepts the attribute, but it doesn't work (http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/13-formaction.html). You will need to create a polyfill for this (wanders over to Sublime Text 2 and starts hacking away...)

Comment: If you're dynamically generating the `formaction` attribute anyway, Isn't it possible to change the `action` attribute on the form at the same time?

Comment: @MrLister Yes, I can do that. If no other solution is available that will be the course I take. It just feels like a bit of a hack to me, whereas I'm endeavoring to code to html 5 standards with fallbacks when I can.

Comment: That's how you'd set the form's `action` attribute dynamically without HTML5, so it certainly isn't a hack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could bind to the submit button with jQuery, extract the `formAction` and apply it to the action of the `form` element:

Given the following HTML

```
<form action="defaultAction.php" id="myForm">
     <input type="submit" value="save" id="save" formAction="http://example.com/save" />
     <input type="submit" value="delete" id="delete" formAction="http://example.com/delete" />
</form>
```

You'd attach a delegate to the form to listen for click of submit buttons within your form:

```
var myForm = $('#myForm');
myForm.on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function (e) {
    var attr = this.getAttribute('formAction');

    if (attr) {
        myForm[0].action = attr; //Set the form's action to formAction
        //this.form.action = attr; //As per Greg's comment, this is an equivalent statement to above, and should be used if myForm reference doesn't need to be used elsewhere in your script.
    }
});
```

Since the click is applied as a delegate, any new submit buttons dynamically added to the form would also trigger this click function. (*exception* if you bind a click handler directly to the button with `e.stopPropagation()` in it)

Now, when the form submits, it will use the value of `formAction` as its action.

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x27R7/6/) shows the value of `formAction` being retrieved in the click handler.

*Edit* Actually, it does "click" the default submit button, even if, for example, you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in a focused text field.

Comment: You can replace `myForm[0].action = this.formAction` with `this.form.action = this.getAttribute("formaction")`. I'm not sure what DOM property, if any, the `formaction` attribute will set. Since `this` refers to a button, `this.form` refers to the form it is a member of, and falling back to `this.getAttribute(...)` is probably the way to go for a pollyfill.

Comment: I already have a reference for `myForm[0]` which is effectively the same reference as `this.form`. They have the same overhead, and are both equally swapable. I agree with your sentiment about using `getAttribute(...)` and will add that to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: You are correct in saying the `myForm[0]` is effectively the same reference as `this.form`, however the advantage of using `this.form` is that a global variable is no longer required.

Comment: @GregBurghardt That's a good point in the limited scope of the presented problem. If he needs the reference to `myForm` nowhere else, then converting it to `$('#myForm').on()` and referencing `this.form` is certainly the better practice.

Comment: @crush This is not working in IE 11, and presumably previous versions as well, although I have not had the chance to test it in anything prior to 11. I will test it further to try to determine why.

Comment: Actually, the problem was the `this.form.action` line. As soon as I changed it back to the initial answer, it started working fine. I will accept this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[formaction](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/13-formaction.html)  is an HTML5 attribute. This is how you use it

```
<form action="/url" >
     <input type="submit" value="save1" id="save1" formAction="http://example.com/save1" />
     <input type="submit" value="save2" id="save2" formAction="http://example.com/save2" />
</form>
```

Here is a fallback what you need.

```
if (!('formAction' in document.createElement('input'))){
 $('form').on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function (e) {
    var attr = this.getAttribute('formAction');

    if (attr) {
        this.action = attr; //Set the form's action to formAction
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Good, But it seems that instead of `this.action = attr;` we have to write something like as `this.form.action = attr;` as here `this` refers to the input element not its parent form!