# Solve nested forms issue

Tags: html, razor, forms

## Problem

I have an MVC Razor partial view that I need to allow an HTTP POST from. This partial view is contained in a view that contains a form that encapsulates the partial view. ie, I need to nest forms.

Given that I can't alter the outer view, what is the best solution?

## Solution 1 - Frig the HTML in the partial view

I could close the form in the view and then reopen it at the end. This is obviously not ideal because a) it leaves the HTML invalid in the partial view and b) it could easily cause problems in the future if the template is changed.

## Solution 2 - Use the formAction attribute

I could use the one outer form and a submit button with the formaction attribute. This would probably be the ideal solution, but unfortunately [doesn't seem to be supported by IE9](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/13-formaction.html).

## Solution 3 - Use JavaScript

I don't really want to go there.

## Update

I've decided to use [the `formAction` attribute backed up by JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904873/is-there-a-way-to-set-up-a-fallback-for-the-input-formaction-attribute-in-html) in case the browser doesn't support it.

Comment: Why not use jQuery to submit the partial view values back to a controller action? since you cannot nest form tags, that seems to be your only option without changing the parent form.

Comment: Upon reflection (excuse the pun) I think I'll use formAction and javaScript while we need to support IE9.